# JFrog Artifactory start up

Tags: devops, artifactory

I have an issue during the start up Artifactory Jfrog version 6.9.0 on rhel 7. To start it up, I installed the artifactory following the instruction from https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-RPMorDebianInstallation
I chose RPM installation method. After the first boot, I did some more steps(add a master.key, configured database connection to mssql), I got next ERRORs in catalina.out

```
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/access]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 15, 2020 6:01:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has finished in [8,738] ms
Sep 15, 2020 6:01:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
Sep 15, 2020 6:01:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [16] ms
Sep 15, 2020 6:01:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Sep 15, 2020 6:01:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
Sep 15, 2020 6:01:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
2020-09-15 06:01:27,782 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'remote' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/binary-store-client-3.2.0.jar!/
2020-09-15 06:01:27,789 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'empty, external-file, external-wrapper, file-system, cache-fs, retry' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/binary-store-core-3.2.0.jar!/
2020-09-15 06:01:27,846 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'eventual, eventual-cluster, google-storage, google-storage-v2, hdfs, s3Old, s3, s3-storage-v3, sharding, sharding-cluster, state-aware, azure-blob-storage' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addon-filestore-6.9.0.jar!/
2020-09-15 06:01:27,849 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'blob' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-storage-db-6.9.0.jar!/
2020-09-15 06:01:32,318 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactorySchedulerFactoryBean:647) - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2020-09-15 06:01:32,424 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:251) - Artifactory context starting up 55 Spring Beans...
2020-09-15 06:01:32,711 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:414) - Initialized new service id: jfrt@01d48tv3af60af1xrf3r2f0j3s
2020-09-15 06:01:32,720 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.c.EncryptionWrapperFactory:33) - createArtifactoryKeyWrapper  EncryptionWrapperBase{ encodingType=ARTIFACTORY_MASTER, topEncrypter=BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='AES128',  keyId='31BxK'}, formatUsed=DotFormat, decrypters=[BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='AES128',  keyId='31BxK'}]}
2020-09-15 06:01:32,842 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:735) - Could not use local hostname as the server instance id: walstgrddoart01: walstgrddoart01: Name or service not known
2020-09-15 06:01:32,851 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:593) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8040/access (bundled) source: detected
2020-09-15 06:01:32,876 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:353) - Waiting for access server...
2020-09-15 06:01:33,002 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientHttpException:41) - Unrecognized ErrorsModel by Access. Original message: Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
2020-09-15 06:01:33,006 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:364) - Could not ping access server: {}
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createRestResponse(AccessHttpClient.java:162)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:113)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.ping(AccessHttpClient.java:95)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientImpl.ping(AccessClientImpl.java:144)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.waitForAccessServer(AccessServiceImpl.java:359)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.waitForAccessServer(AccessServiceImpl.java:332)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1131)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:305)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessClientIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:294)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:259)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:211)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:67)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:92)
2020-09-15 06:01:35,012 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientHttpException:41) - Unrecognized ErrorsModel by Access. Original message: Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
2020-09-15 06:01:35,012 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:364) - Could not ping access server: {}
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createRestResponse(AccessHttpClient.java:162)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:113)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.ping(AccessHttpClient.java:95)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientImpl.ping(AccessClientImpl.java:144)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.waitForAccessServer(AccessServiceImpl.java:359)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.waitForAccessServer(AccessServiceImpl.java:332)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1131)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:305)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessClientIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:294)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:259)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:211)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:67)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:92)
```

In addition I have found similar solution here: [Artifactory 5.11 fails to start up due to Access failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346694/artifactory-5-11-fails-to-start-up-due-to-access-failure/50349957) But in my case the solution from the topic above doesn't work. Any ideas how to start up Artifactory 6.9.0?

Answer (score 1):

In such a case (Could not ping access server: {}), please verify the **access.log** file from Artifactory, which would give us a hint towards the issue on why the application is unable to ping the Access server. A similar issue could occur when access.log returns "java.security.KeyStoreException" that is caused due to the issue discussed [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8266279). Upgrading Java to a higher version like OpenJDK 11 would help to overcome it.